# jquery tools - tabs mouseover - 2nd

Tags: jquery, tabs, mouseover

I use this tool to show text when moving the mouse over the pix:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/mouseover.htm

Does anybody have an idea how to force that the "context" of the second pic is shown when opening the demo-page instead of the context of the first pic (default)?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

on (approximately) line #88 change:

```
$("#products").tabs("div.description", {event:'mouseover'});
```

to:

```
$("#products").tabs("div.description", {event:'mouseover', 'initialIndex': 1});
```

Where the value of 'initialIndex' is the number of the tab you would like to show starting at zero (eg: tab #1 = 0, tab #2 = 1, tab #3 = 2).

Read more about your options here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs.html